# PHP Not deleting MYSQL Database row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've spent a lot of time messing around with PHP and MYSQL and I've finally managed to create a "to do list" sort of thing that allows the user to submit a "to do" task and for it to add it to a database and then show it. I've followed many tutorials as I've tried to teach myself PHP blah blah. But for some reason i cannot get the delete script working.

```php
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?=Delete" . $row['task_id']."'>Delete"."</a>"."</td></tr>" . "$record->ID";
```

Above is the code for the delete button

Here is the delete script apologies for the many commented out lines I've tried many 'solutions'.

```php
    $ID = $_GET['task_id'];
    //$delete_query = "DELETE FROM Tasks WHERE ID =  $ID" ;
    $sql = "DELETE FROM Tasks WHERE task_id = $ID;";
    echo $row['task_id'];
    // $delete_query = "DELETE FROM Tasks WHERE task_id = ['task_id'] ";
    
    /* if(isset($GET['task_id'])){
       $delete = $_GET['task_id'];
        mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM Tasks WHERE task_id = '$delete'");
    } */
    
    
    
    echo("Succesfully deleted");
    mysqli_close($link);
```

The script runs and it says "successfully deleted" but the entry still shows. In the F12 Menu/Network tab I get this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAdA6.png)

And when I click "view source" it shows the ID of the row. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: It should be `echo "<td><a href='delete.php?task_id=" . $row['task_id']."'>Delete"."</a>"."</td></tr>" . "$record->ID";`. Also, you're open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work).

Comment: Thanks for the response, however that did not work either. I am only experimenting atm just for fun I will look into SQL Injections

Comment: However, that change did make the F12 Menu display the ID not the "empty"

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries (I would treat any answers that ignored this with scepticism) - and consider whether a hard delete is really something that you want to allow users to do.

Comment: **Never** use GET for deletion. Bots can visit those urls and you could lose data.

Comment: @danielfitton Task id is string or integer?

Answer (score 0):

I am try to delete data using `php pdo`. and data can deleted successfully so you can try this code.

I have created 2 file. first `req.php` and second `delete.php`.

Here `req.php` file can fetch data and `delete.php` file can delete this data from send `req.php` file id.

req.php

```
<?php

require "connection.php";

//This is a fetch data from database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
$select = $conn->prepare($sql);
$select->execute();

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Data</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>EMAIL</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        
            while($data = $select->fetch())
            {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $data['id']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['student_name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['email_address']; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>"><button onclick="return conformation();">Delete</button></a></td> <!-- This is a delete data button ---> 
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    //This is a conformation function if it will return true then data can delete otherwise data cannot deleted.
    function conformation() {
        let conform = confirm("Can you delete this data ?"); 
        
        if (conform == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

delete.php

```
<?php

require "connection.php";

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM test WHERE id = ?";
    $deleteData = $conn->prepare($sql);
    
    if ($deleteData->execute([$_GET['id']])) 
    {
        header('location: http://local.test/req.php');
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, I tried to create a new test page to see if it worked but it wouldn't return any of the data so I tried to add it into the existing code like:

 echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $data['task_id'] . "<button onclick='return conformation();'>Delete</button></a>";

But now when I hover over the link it shows it as : /test/delete.php?id=<button%20onclick>

Comment: Also this code does not show the text, it has the amount of entries in the database but does not show text only white space with the delete button visible

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this or debug it by doing the following.

1. parse the right URL parameter

   ```php
      echo "<td><a href='delete.php?task_id=" . $row['task_id']."'>Delete"."</a>"."</td></tr>" . "$record->ID";
   ```

this will send a task_id value to the delete page.

2. checking and logging the response of my SQL in delete.php

   ```php
        if(isset($_REQUEST['task_id'])){

         //escape to avoid SQL injection
         $delete = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_REQUEST['task_id']);

         $process = mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM Tasks WHERE task_id = '".$delete."'");

         if($process){
            echo("Succesfully deleted");
         }else{
           echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($connect));
        }
      }else{
        echo("no id supplied");
      }
   ```

in your question, you also had this: **$GET['task_id']**, which I believe was null.

Comment: Thanks for the response, tried this but it just says the echo of "Error description" but nothing after that

Answer (score -1):

The first issue is trying to get task_id from REQUEST params while you sending "Delete" key.

The second is you passed the task_id to db as a string, while I think it's an Integer type in the database.

So you have to do that:

```
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?task_id=" . $row['task_id']."'>Delete"."</a>"."</td></tr>" . "$record->ID";

$task_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET['task_id']);

if (!empty($task_id)) {
    $delete_query = mysqli_query($connect, 'DELETE FROM Tasks WHERE task_id = '.$task_id);
   if ($delete_query) {
      echo 'deleted successfully';
   } else {
      echo("Error: " . mysqli_error($connect));
   }
} else {
     echo 'task_id is empty !';
}
```

Comment: Also tried this but I just get the echo of task_id is empty